# Dialog shows every time?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, algorithm

For some reason, my permission check dialog shows every time, but it should only show once:

I have the following code that checks for an SMS permission in my `onCreate()`:

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You should enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /*ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1001
                );*/


            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1
                        );
            }
        }
```

The problem is, even if the user **does** click enable in `onCreate`, the app opens up the permission dialog the next time the user opens the app. Shouldn't the permission be granted, and the dialog not show again?

Comment: You are checking for `READ_CONTACTS` and requesting `SEND_SMS`

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS instead of Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS